# How to interconnect (listener/action) separate elements in Mootools 1.4?

Tags: mootools

I have a little issue with mootools 1.4 and interaction between multiple separate elements. I have a menu like this :

```
<div id="links">
<a class="readmore" href="#1" title="1">Read More</a>
<a class="readmore" href="#2" title="2">Read More</a>
<a class="readmore" href="#2" title="3">Read More</a>
...
</div>
```

And an other element like this :
Code PHP:

```
<div id="content">
<div id="1">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="2">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div id="3">Lorem Ipsum</div>
...
</div>
```

Both are the same length (each link of the menu have a correspondant div element). What I need to do is to create a listener on each menu link so when it’s click it display the div. And that’s where my problem is because for the moment I use the title of the menu link to open the div that have the same ID. I don’t think that is the most performant, maybe I can do all this in one loop with the index ?

Other little question (not as important at all) : How to put add the same event on 2 element in one line of code (to avoid the multiplication of line of code to do exactly the same thing if the user click on different button) ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

several things can be done.

#### - event delegation

idea: attach a single event to parent of menu items which fires dependent on the child el that has matched the event condition

so:

```
document.id('links').addEvent('click:relay(a.readmore)', function(event, element){
    var id = element.get('title');
    // do something.
});
```

downside is that you need to read the id but you can remove the ids from the target els if they are in the right order.

```
(function() {    
    var els = document.getElements('#content div');

    document.id('links').addEvent('click:relay(a.readmore)', function(event, element){
        var id = element.get('title'),
            hint = els[id-1];

        showHint(hint);
    });
}());
```

that's about it. less events attached.

#### - looping to attach the events has a reference to index, which will match target

```
(function() {    
    var els = document.getElements('#content div'),
        clickHandler = function(trigger, target){

        };

    document.getElements('#links a').each(function(element, index){
        element.addEvent('click', function(event) {
            event.stop();
            clickHandler(this, els[index]));
        });
    });
}());
```

upside to that is, you don't need ids on hint els and no title tags or anything on source. downside, each link has its own click event.

Comment: Thanks I think both ideas can help me a lot. I'll try that quickly